# joomla 3 redirect to thank you page after registration

Tags: joomla3.0

how can I redirect to a thank you page after registration in joomla 3?
By default joomla redirect to login page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [free](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/redirect-on-login) or [paid](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/redirect-on-login-pro) version of Redirect on Login can do this for you.

Comment: Thanks Neil but the function is available only in the free version. Is there any other solution? For example a code override?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you could probably do this with an override or a plugin.